# Compute eigens with numba cuda

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numba

I got problem with compute large covariance matrix to get eigen's values (values and vectors). So I tried with GPU. I found numba and tried with jit which default using CPU. it takes less longer, but I can't use my CPU for computation things. I tried with target flags with cuda like this:

```
 from numba import jit, cuda
 import numpy as np
 from time import time
 @jit(target="cuda")
 def eigens(a):
     val, vec = np.linalg.eig(a)
     return val, vec

 t1 = time()
 a = np.array([[1 + 0j, 2 + 0j], [1 + 0j, 1 + 0j]])
 print(eigens(a))
 t2 = time()
 print("t: ", t2 - t1)
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
numba.errors.TypingError: Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
No conversion from (array(complex128, 1d, C), array(complex128, 2d, F)) to 
none for '$0.12', defined at None
File "numba-test.py", line 9
[1] During: typing of assignment at 
C:/Users/blackbox/PycharmProjects/MechaGodzilla/numba-test.py (9)
```

I've tried without flags and run perfectly fine. As I need now its just using the GPU to compute numpy library. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

**Edit:** I'm using python 3.5 with conda (64-bit). It's there any alternate to compute an eigen from numpy with GPU?

Comment: You can use `cupy` to compute eigenvalues on the GPU